# Javascript Clock without Seconds

Tags: javascript, clock

I have found [this script](http://www.cblt.soton.ac.uk/authoring/rtf-xml/jscripts/imageclock.htm) online and added my own images into it. The only problem is whenever I try to remove `var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()` it doesn't work anymore, meaning it stops updating.

However, when I keep the script in its original format, the clock does live update. How do I get the clock to update every minute? I only want the hours and minutes.

Comment: I looked at that code and wanted to throw up. That code is just... disgusting.

Comment: I thought @NiettheDarkAbsol was overreacting but after checking the code I think he is right. The main ingredients for a clock are a `setInterval` function and a `Date` object.

Comment: What do you expect after removing a variable declaration which is certainly used after ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code in such a way that actually works properly (although I still don't like `document.images`... but it'll do)

```
var imgs = {}, i;
for( i=0; i<10; i++) {
    imgs[i] = new Image();
    imgs[i].src = "c"+i+".gif";
}
imgs.blank = new Image(); imgs.blank.src = "cb.gif";
imgs.am = new Image(); imgs.am.src = "cam.gif";
imgs.pm = new Image(); imgs.pm.src = "cpm.gif";

function extract(h,m,s,dn){
    document.images.a.src = imgs[Math.floor(h/10) || "blank"].src;
    document.images.b.src = imgs[h%10].src;

    document.images.d.src = imgs[Math.floor(m/10)].src;
    document.images.e.src = imgs[m%10].src;

    document.images.g.src = imgs[Math.floor(s/10)].src;
    document.images.h.src = imgs[s%10].src;

    if( dn=="AM") document.images.j.src = imgs.am.src;
    else document.images.j.src = imgs.pm.src;
}
function show3(){
    var Digital = new Date(),
        h = Digital.getHours(),
        m = Digital.getMinutes(),
        s = Digital.getSeconds(),
        dn = h >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    extract( h%12 || 12, m, s, dn)
    setTimeout(show3,1000);
}
```

Now, if you want to get rid of seconds, comment out these lines:

```
//    document.images.g.src = imgs[Math.floor(s/10)].src;
//    document.images.h.src = imgs[s%10].src;
```

And remove the `g` and `h` images from your HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the seconds, they're needed to increase minutes every 60 seconds. But you can choose not to display them.

But considering the script, you would have a better result making yourself the script, using `setInterval` and `Date` as A1rPun said.